# Intersection of indexed finite collection of infinite sets is an infinite set

Tags: elementary-set-theory

I am trying to figure out how to write out the proof to this.

If $I = \{n_{1}, \ldots, n_{k}\}$ is any finite subset of $\mathbb{N}$, then
$$\bigcap_{i \in I}i\mathbb{Z}$$

is an infinite set.

Below is what I thought:
for $n = 1$, $n = 2$, $n = 3$, $n = 4$, ...,
we have $1\mathbb{Z}$,$2\mathbb{Z}$,$3\mathbb{Z}$,$4\mathbb{Z}$,...

Those $n$s have a lowest common multiple $m$ 
and $m\mathbb{Z} =\bigcap_{i \in I}i\mathbb{Z}$ and $m\mathbb{Z}$ is an infinite set since $\mathbb{Z}$ is an infinite set.

Am I on the right track? If I am, is there any glitch in my proof?
Thank you!

Comment: What _exactly_ is it you're trying to prove? You have a "then" without any matching "if", which I suppose should be at the beginning of the line -- but much worse is that what comes _after_ the "then" is _not something that can be true or false_, but just an expression that evaluates to a particular set.

Comment: @HenningMakholm Sorry, I made some mistakes while typing the problem out. Now I have corrected them. Thank you for pointing out!

Comment: @Crostul Sorry, I have correct it. Thank you for pointing it out!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I think I understand what you are asking, and your proof contains the essentials of the answer. I re-express it below.

Let $I = \{n_{i}\}_{i = 1, k}$ be a finite set of $k $ integers. and $n_{i}\mathbb{Z} $ is the set of multiples of of $n_{i}$.

Prove that $\bigcap_{i = 1, k} n_{i}\mathbb{Z}$ is an infinite set.

Proof: let $m$ be the lowest common multiple of $\{n_{i}\}_{i = 1, k}$ which exists since $k$ is finite. Then $m\mathbb{Z} \subset n_{i}\mathbb{Z} $ for all $i =1, k $. So $m\mathbb{Z} \subset \bigcap_{i = 1, k}n_{i}\mathbb{Z}$ and since  $m\mathbb{Z} $ is infinite then so is $\bigcap_{i = 1, k}n_{i}\mathbb{Z}$

(Proof: $m\mathbb{Z} \subset n_{i}\mathbb{Z} $ for all $i \in I$.

By definition of LCM for any $n_i$ we have $m = p.n_i$ where $p$ is an integer. So, for any $z \in \mathbb{Z}$  then $z.m = z.p.n_i$. But $z.p = z' \in \mathbb{Z}$ so $z.m = z'.n_i \in n_i\mathbb{Z}$. Therefore $m\mathbb{Z} \subset n_{i}\mathbb{Z} $ )